# marklogic content pump URI containing square brackets

Tags: uri, marklogic, marklogic-8, mlcp

I try to load documents using MLCP import and the `-output_uri_replace` option, such as

```
-output_uri_replace 
".*/,'',---,':',___,'/'"
```

Everything is ok, except that I need to keep square brackets in my URIs and MLCP always encode them into `%5B` and `%5D`

I have tried different patterns to force it (or no pattern at all) but no way...

```
-output_uri_replace
".*/,'',---,':',___,'/',\[,'U\+005B',\],'\]'"
```

Anyone with the same experience or with a solution? :)

Comment: Haven't tried, but perhaps worth looking into using a MLCP transform to override the uri.

Comment: Just found confirmation that the square brackets should be okay: https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/254/0/valid-characters-in-a-marklogic-document-uri. Not sure why MLCP is encoding them.

Comment: MLCP uses Java's `URI.encode()`: https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-contentpump/blob/master/mapreduce/src/main/java/com/marklogic/mapreduce/DocumentURI.java#L136, which will escape square brackets, since the URI spec doesn't allow them in the path portion. I think @grtjn is right, the only way would be to have a transform that writes to the un-escaped URI on ingest.

Answer (score 0):

I played around a little too, and it looks like `-output_uri_replace` is executed before the uri gets encoded. The only secure way to undo unwanted uri encoding, is to use a transform. Something like the following seems to do the trick:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

module namespace ingest = "http://marklogic.com/ingest-transform";

declare option xdmp:mapping "false";

declare function ingest:transform(
  $content as map:map,
  $context as map:map
) as map:map*
{
  let $uri := map:get($content, "uri")
  let $doc := map:get($content, "value")
  let $_ := map:put($content, "uri", fn:replace(fn:replace($uri, "%5B", "["), "%5D", "]"))
  return $content
};
```

HTH!

Comment: Thank you for your time and thoughts, I finally did a post processing like yours.